# How to set Firestore security rules? resource.data: Null value error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need some help making my security rules for firestore work.

These are my firestore rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /orders/{orderID} {
       allow read, update: if  request.auth.uid == resource.data.buyerId  || request.auth.uid == resource.data.sellerId;
    }
  }
}
```

my orders collection:

```
orders: {
sellerId: 'some-id',
createdAt: timestamp,
buyerId: 'some-id'
}
```

It should return all documents from orders collection which has either buyerId or sellerId equal to authorised user (request.auth.uid).

but the above rule is not working as expected.

[firestore collections screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt7Bn.jpg)

[firebase simulator output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R981W.png)

Comment: What is the exact query you are using to fetch the documents?

Comment: I am testing it in firebase simulator and getting - Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [4], column [52]. Null value error.

Comment: Do you mean you are querying for all the documents of the orders collection? Could you add a print screen of the simulator?

Comment: I have added firebase simulator output

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That error message is suggesting that the requested document was not actually present in the database.  You entered "orders/{orderId}", which looks like you put a wildcard in the Location field in the simulator.  That's not going to work.  You need to enter the path to an *actual* document that exists if you want to test your rule that uses its field values.

Comment: orders collection already exists with the fields sellerId and buyerId

Comment: Sure, but there is no document with id {orderId}.  You need to put an actual document ID there if you want to test against its contents.  You can't use a wildcard in the simulator panel.

Comment: I have edited post with attached firestore collections screenshot, there are some documents already present in the orders collection.

Comment: you were right, when putting orders/DePzMaZAMkJUcH66fIxA in location field of simulator it worked fine.

Comment: What to do for matching any document in the collection, could you please suggest?

Comment: You can't simulate a match against any document, in the same way that you can't make a query that fetches an unknown document.  You need to know the document you're trying to access.

Comment: Looks like I have the same issue. I've created git repo with tests. Could you please look at this
https://github.com/OleksiiBrylin/firestore-rules

Answer (score 10):

`resource.data: Null` - this error happens when you try to create a new entity.

Split `write` rule, on `create` and `update`.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /user/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;

      function authed() {
        return request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
      allow create: if authed() && request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['name']);
      allow update: if authed() && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).changedKeys().hasOnly(['name']);
      allow delete: if authed();
    }
  }
}
```