# Troubleshoot simple custom firebase security rules function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing a custom cloud function ([official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#custom_functions)) in Firestore security rules that checks to make sure the submitting user is the content owner, per the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#authentication).

I'm applying the custom function to the correct path `/collection/{documents}/subcollection/{subcollectiondocuments}` where every `subcollectiondocument` has a `userId` field that's not null. These documents do not have a `uid` field, but I tried it anyway in 2 and 4 below.

All versions of the custom function below (belongsToRequestor 1,2,3 and 4) generate a "Property resource is undefined on object" error in the Cloud Firestore rules playground simulator.

Do I need to pass something into the custom function, or am I making some other mistake?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
  function belongsToRequestor1() {
      return
      request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
    }


  function belongsToRequestor2() {
      return
      request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }

  function belongsToRequestor3() {
      return
      request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId;
    }

  function belongsToRequestor4() {
      return
      request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;
    }
   
   …
   match /collection/{documents}/subcollection/{subcollectiondocuments} {
    
   allow update: if
      belongsToRequestor1(); 
      // or belongsToRequestor2(); or belongsToRequestor3(); or belongsToRequestor4();

   …

   } }
```

I'm not sure how to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55961623/1459653) to another question to "…enter the path to an actual document that exists if you want to **test** your rule that uses its field values."  Each document in `subcollectiondocuments` has an id auto-generated by firebase.

Update: adding database screenshot (with fake data), as requested (properties = collection and reviews == subcollection):

[image: screenshot with fake data]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your Firestore collections? When you try to update a sub-document, `resource.data` would be an object contain data of the document being updated. I assume the uid, userId fields are present in the document of root collection. If that's the case, then you'll have to use `get()` function to read data from that document. Can you share the screenshots to confirm this?

Comment: So a "review" document can only update the creator only i.e. person with UID same as `userId` field in that review doc itself? Where are UID of requestor1 and 2 coming from? I cannot see any `uid` in any of the documents.

Comment: You're right @Dharmaraj, as I wrote above, "These documents do not have a uid field, but I tried it anyway in 2 and 4 below."  Yes, looking to have only the creator be able to update.

Comment: I saw this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56487579/1459653 - after posting and tried the isMine() code.  ```request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId``` and ```request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid``` resulted in the following error in the security rules simulator: "Property resource is undefined on object"

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation's ```get()``` function, as @Dharmaraj suggests above: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0#access_other_documents  Novices like me should note that "…The get() and exists() functions both expect fully specified document paths…"   I tried ```request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/properties/$(property)/reviews/$(review)).data.userId;``` and received an "Invalid variable name: review" error. Even if I can get this working, this may not be a good custom function, since diff paths will be needed…

Comment: Are you using this match statement as-is? `match /collection/{documents}/subcollection/{subcollectiondocuments}` I tried a concept example using `belongsToRequestor1()` as the function checking for the same `userId` as the request auth id, and it was allowed as expected. It could also be a syntax error. If you can share a full rules file that triggers this error, it could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Ernesto. I did use that match statement, though with the actual collection & document names instead of "collection", "documents" etc. Sorry, but I'm away for a few days and can't access my code. Best, -M